# Content property is undefined in new Brunch-Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, brunch

I am starting new Ember application using the Brunch skeleton: [Brunch with Ember](https://github.com/icholy/ember-brunch). I have created a simple ApplicationController and set the content property to an empty object:

```
var App = require('app');

App.ApplicationController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: { }
});
```

But when I load the application in the browser, the content property of App.ApplicationController.content is undefined.  Also the set and pushObject functions are also not defined on the App.ApplicationController.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have defined your Controller class there. You need to **create an instance of the Class**.

Normally you do it with:

```
App.initialize();
```

In this case Ember will instantiate the controller for you. And you will find your controller in the path App.router.applicationController.

But you could also instantiate the Controller manually, e.g.:

```
App.yourController = App.ApplicationController.create();
```

Comment: Thanks, but Brunch with Ember does do an App.initialize() in initialize.js which is called from my index. Trying to instantiate it manually (with .create vs. .extend) causes the application to fail completely with "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must have an ApplicationController defined on your application"  Assuming that the order in which branch compiles the application doesn't like it being instantiated at that time, since it does it later.

Comment: Ok, i didnnot know that. But than your mistake was to test your stuff on App.ApplicationController. As i sais this is only your class. If Brunch didnthe App.initialize() for you, you will find the controller instance at App.router.applicationController. The content of this object should be not undefined and the mentioned method pushObject should work.

Comment: Could you post the code that actually worked?  i.e., how did you "call them through the router"?

Comment: @Kevin: This question refers to an outdated version of Ember. So the answer would not help that much, i think. Maybe you post an own question and i will have a lok at it? Notify me here, when you posted it.